# I am getting error in cloning a file. It is saying that i don't have access rights while my collegue can clone it from that repository

Tags: github

[Here I have cloned the file but i can't see the the project it is showing "not found" and that i don't have access rights.I am using Crio website "https://crio.do/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwlMy.jpg)

Comment: You can copy-paste the output of the VS Code  terminal directly in the question, as text. That would be much clearer and easier to answer in many aspects. For instance, the exact command you use is cut, and cannot be seen exactly. See also : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251

Comment: Are you sure you have actually cloned the repository? could you please also give the command you used for the cloning.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the issue is solved.